# django combining two query set and called it to html

Tags: python, django

I have this queryset in views.py, I am using union to combine the two queryset, how am i combine the two queryset using another models, (INNER JOIN in sql) and called it to the html? please check also the html ive given specially in temperature

```
company = FmCustomerUsers.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
employee = FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier.objects.filter(
        fmCustomerID__company_name__in=company.values_list('fmCustomerID__company_name'))
feedback = TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords.objects.filter(
        fmCustomerID__company_name__in=company.values_list('fmCustomerID__company_name')).filter(
        fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID__in=employee.values_list('id')).union(TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords.objects.filter(
        fmCustomerID__company_name__in=company.values_list('fmCustomerID__company_name')))
```

this is my models.py

```
class FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier(models.Model):
    fmCustomerID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Customer")
    fmCustomerLocationID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomerLocation', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="CustomerLocation")
    dateSubmitted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    middleInitial = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    bodyTemperature = models.FloatField()
    fmCustomerSectionID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomerSection', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="CustomerSection")
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
   

class TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords(models.Model):
    fmCustomerID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomer',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Customer")
    fmCustomerLocationID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomerLocation', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="CustomerLocation")
    dateSubmitted = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    middleInitial = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    bodyTemperature = models.FloatField()
    fmCustomerSectionID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomerSection',  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="CustomerSection")
    employee_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    contactNumber = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    


class TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords(models.Model):

    fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                                     verbose_name="CustomerEmployeeSupplier")
    fmCustomerID = models.ForeignKey('FmCustomer',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Customer")
    dateSubmitted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    q1Answer = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    q2Answer = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    q2AnswerDetailed = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    q3Answer = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    q4Answer = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    q4AnswerDetailed = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    q5Answer = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    q5Ubo = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    q5Lagnat = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    q5Sipon = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    q5LBM = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    q5HirapSaPaghinga = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    q5PananakitngUlo = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    q5PananakitngKatawan = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    q5PagkawalaNgPangAmoyatPanlasa = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    q6visitedPlacesDuringNonWorkingDays = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

this is my html

```
{% for feedback in feedbacks %}

                    <tr>
                    <td> {{feedback.id}} </td> 
                    <td> {{feedback.inputdate}} </td>
                    <td> {{feedback.fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID.firstname}} {{feedback.fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID.middleInitial}} {{feedback.fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID.lastname}}</td>
                    <td> {{feedback.fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID.fmCustomerLocationID}} </td>
                    <td> {{feedback.fmCustomerID.fmCustomerLocationID}} </td>
                    <td> {{feedback.fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID.contactNumber}} </td>
                     <td> {{feedback.fmCustomerID.section}} </td>
                    <td> {{feedback.fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID.bodyTemperature}} </td> ====> this td is for model `TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords`
                    <td>{{feedback.q1Answer}}</td>
                </tr>
```

this my traceback

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (each UNION query must have the same number of columns
LINE 1: ...U2."id") WHERE U0."user_id" = 2)))) UNION (SELECT "TracingAp...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ContractTracingProject\TracingSettings\TracingApp\views.py" in report1
  1169.     return render(request, "TracingApp/report1.html", {"feedbacks": feedback})

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  166.             len_values = len(values)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  256.         self._fetch_all()

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  1242.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __iter__
  55.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1100.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /report1/
Exception Value: each UNION query must have the same number of columns
LINE 1: ...U2."id") WHERE U0."user_id" = 2)))) UNION (SELECT "TracingAp...
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That not very complicated and the error is self explanatory :

```py
each UNION query must have the same number of columns
```

Your code is such a mess that you didnt see it :

`TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords` and `TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords` are different

and look at this :

`contact_number` in `FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier`
`contactNumber` in `TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords`

You'r code should be :

```py
companies_name = FmCustomerUsers.objects.filter(
    user=request.user.id
).values_list('fmCustomerID__company_name')

employees_id = FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier.objects.filter(
    fmCustomerID__company_name__in=companies_name
).values_list('id')

employees_feedback = TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords.objects.filter(
    fmCustomerID__company_name__in=companies_name,
    fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID__in=employees_id
)

customers_feedback = TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords.objects.filter(
    fmCustomerID__company_name__in=companies_name,
    fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID__in=employees_id
)

feedback = employees_feedback.union(customers_feedback)
```

You just need to add a `values_list` on both `employees_feedback` and `customers_feedback` with the same fields needed

You need to follow PEP8, because it's hard to read you

Comment: im my model `TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords` i dont have  `fmCustomerEmployeeSupplierID` field

Comment: each UNION query must have the same number of columns
LINE 1: ...= U2."id") WHERE U0."user_id" = 2)) UNION (SELECT "TracingAp...

Comment: So, you cannot do what you want to do, conception problem not code problem (create abstract model will help you here)

Comment: is there a way to get what i want without creating abstract model?

Comment: Man for speaking the true, all your code is bad writting, start anew, rationalise it. `FmCustomerEmployeeSupplier` and `TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords` are the same, that make no sence because you want `TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords` and `TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords` to be the same

Comment: oh, thanks for this mr @MaximeK, it really help me to better understanding the `union` i think i will change my database schema.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a UNION of two queries that don't have the same number of rows.

You are trying to union:

- TrEmployeeSuppliersFeedbackQuestionsSubmittedRecords (19 rows)
- TrCustomerEmployeeSupplierSubmittedRecords (12 rows)

You just can't do this.
All I can tell is you should only select the fields you need to get in your final query in order to have equal number of fields on both side of the query. Maybe using the *values_list* or *only* queryset methods.

Comment: can you please provide an example?